# Error in adding date condition in wpdb prepare

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, prepare

How to add a condition date in wpdb prepare? What's wrong with this code?

```
$results= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date = DATE_FORMAT(%s, "%%Y-%%m-%%d")',$date),OBJECT);
```

Thanks

Comment: what is error ???

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_FORMAT()` is a function and should not be used inside prepare statement.

You should either store

```
$dt = DATE_FORMAT($s, "Y-m-d")
```

and use `$dt` wherever required or you can do

```
$wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date = '. DATE_FORMAT($s, "Y-m-d"),OBJECT);
```